how to get summary of number of additions and deletions per commit and user for each day in git
So far I have been reading the below two responses:

How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?
https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/3fb7ef0c0cbdb72412fc

But I have been trouble getting exactly what I need. Here is what I have so far:
git log --date=iso --numstat \
    --pretty=format:'%ad%x08%aN %s' \
    --author="some_author"

This yields:
2024-08-20 14:10:15 -070some_author other_commit (#2)
75      10      file3

2024-08-20 13:54:21 -070some_author some_commit (#1)
11      7       file1
3       2       file2

But I am having trouble with awk extracting the total number of lines added and delete per timestamp. I.e. what I want is:
some_author,2024-08-20 14:10:15,75,10
some_author,2024-08-20 13:54:21,14,9

Ideally, I don't want to specify the user and want results generated like above for all users in the repo, but maybe that is not doable.

Please show what you tried, and explain what is wrong with it.

What this metric will be useful to, I wonder. I just hope you don't try to measure the amount of work per contributor. Because such metric would not achieve that.

can some_author contain spaces? It sounds from "I don't want to specify the user..." like you don't want your starting point to be git log ...  --author="some_author" but some other command that doesn't have a --author="some_author" option - if so, show that command and it's multi-user output and the expected final output in your question rather than the command you apparently don't want to process.

My original proposal using an array is overkill, just deleted it and use a regular awk workflow:
git .. | awk -v OFS=, '
    /^20[0-9][0-9]-/{
        k = substr($3,5) OFS $1" "$2; /* find user + timestamp */ 
        t1 = 0; t2 = 0;               /* reset sub-total */
        next
    }
    { t1 += $1; t2 += $2 }            /* calc the sub-total */
    /^$/{ print k, t1, t2 }           /* print sub-total on blank line */  
    END{ print k, t1, t2 }            /* print info for the last commit */
' 


For some reason OP's current pretty format includes a backspace (%x08) which overwrites the last digit of the timezone offset while making the output harder to parse; assuming OP has the ability to change the format:
###########
# replace this:

'%ad%x08%aN %s'  ==>  2024-08-20 14:10:15 -070some_author other_commit (#2)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

###########
# with this:

'%ad %aN %s'     ==>  2024-08-20 14:10:15 -0700 some_author other_commit (#2)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

OP's output should then look like:
$ cat git_log.out
2024-08-20 14:10:15 -0700 some_author other_commit (#2)
75      10      file3

2024-08-20 13:54:21 -0700 some_author some_commit (#1)
11      7       file1
3       2       file2

One awk approach:
$ cat git_log.awk
function printme() {
    if (output != "")                          # if non-empty then ...
       print output OFS sum1 OFS sum2          # print to stdout
    output = ""                                # reset variables
    sum1 = sum2 = 0
}

BEGIN            { OFS = "," }
/^20[0-9][0-9]-/ { printme()                   # print previous entry to stdout
                   output = $4 OFS $1 " " $2
                   next
                 }
/^[[:digit:]]/   { sum1 += $1
                   sum2 += $2
                 }
END              { printme() }                 # flush last entry to stdout

NOTES:

this works as long as OP continues to overwrite the author with the literal string `some_author' (containing no white space)
if OP modifies the git log call such that an author is displayed that contains white space then it will be necessary to modify this script (ideally OP would modify --pretty=format: to make parsing easier)

Taking for a test drive:
$ awk -f git_log.awk git_log.out
some_author,2024-08-20 14:10:15,75,10
some_author,2024-08-20 13:54:21,14,9

If OP wants to pipe/redirect the output from the git log call  directly into awk:
git log ... | awk -f git_log.awk -

##### or

awk -f git_log.awk <(git log ...)

